# Any PHP function to convert invalid characters in Cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, invalid-characters

I got this: Warning: Cookie values can not contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014'

is there a function to remove those?  and also convert the "+" sign in to %2B ?

Comment: What are you trying to put into the cookie?

Comment: Why not just strip them before creating the cookie? You can use something like `str_replace()` or a regex function to find these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I use base64_encode  to do that.

Answer (score 1):

try `urlencode($cookie_value);`

Comment: @murvinlai do you get the same error message? You are 100% sure?